# Setting a parameter (background color) for multiple objects

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I was trying to add a button to my program, which changes the color of all the other buttons. So in the `ActionPerformed` of that button. I would like to assign `.setBackground(Color.red)` for multiple `JButton` components at once, instead of writing them all down. Is that possible?

Comment: *"I would like to assign `.setBackground(Color.red)` for multiple `JButton` components at once, instead of writing them all down."* Use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an array of buttons and then use a loop to set the background color:

```
JButton[] buttons = {jButton1, jButton2, jButton3};
for(JButton button: buttons){
    button.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about changing all the buttons' backgrounds, not some of them, you can use `UIManager.put("Button.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));` and then invoke `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f)` where `f` is your running `JFrame`. This way you can change all the buttons' properties without actually obfuscating your code.